# How do you block emails from appearing as links in FreeMarker?

Tags: freemarker

I'm working on some ftl templates and email addresses are coming through as links, specifically on mobile browsers and in Outlook.

Anyone know how to block this from happening?

Thanks in advance!

Note: I am not adding them as links, just the email itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a FreeMarker problem.  Your using FreeMarker to simply generate HTML.  If the HTML being produced is creating an HTML email link, then you need to modify template text, not any freemarker directive or setting.

I assume the template currently looks something like

```
<a href="mailto:${emailAddress}">Send Email</a>
```

change it to just

`${emailAddress}`

Comment: I had to make some assumptions because I'm not 100% percent sure of what your doing, if I am incorrect please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but not really. I guess I wasn't clear in my question... I'm putting in the email as is, no surrounding links.

Comment: It is still not a freemarker problem.  You could be using Velocity, or JSP and render the same HTML.  Did you try using a <pre> tag?

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestion, I'll let you know.

Comment: It actually didn't the email showed up in courier... but still as a link

Comment: It looks like it's an outlook issue. Not freemarker. Not even the <pre> tag helped.

Answer (score 0):

This has most probably nothing to do with Freemarker. What you are observing is an issue depending on how e-mail clients handle and display e-mails. Some clients just try to "help", identifying web and e-mail addresses etc. and then making them links.

Depending on the Mime type, different mail clients have different ways handling/displaying e-mails. Outlook e.g. sometimes does not display all attachments. It is anything but trivial to send out e-mails that display well in every mail client out there.

This [thread on sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/microsoft-office/188125-outlook-2010-urls-no-longer-display-hyperlinks-when-reading-mail.html) states that you can trigger hyperlink replacement on or off in the options:

- File > Options > Mail > Editor Options > AutoCorrect Options > AutoFormat tab > Replace > Internet and network paths with hyperlinks