# Keycloak's FreeMarker email template

Tags: html-email, freemarker, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak to send a forgot password email, and from what I've read on their docs and the FreeMarker docs, it seems like I should be able to use HTML tags just fine. However, when I use them in the password-rest.ftl file, it renders the whole tag like so:

```
<p>Some Text</p>
```

instead of just showing: Some Text

I found this (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-681) saying that Keycloak can only send plain text emails, and I just wanted to see if anyone knew for sure since I have found some stuff that looks like the HTML tags should be usable [How do you block emails from appearing as links in FreeMarker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275430/how-do-you-block-emails-from-appearing-as-links-in-freemarker)

Any advice or thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are two sub-directories containing templates for emails. They are called `text` and `html`. When you want HTML you need to edit templates located in `html` directory.

*Keycloak* itself sends emails as multi-part messages containing both *plain-text* and *HTML* versions - email client decides which one is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Keycloak, but somehow you should set the Mime type of your e-mail to `"text/html"` (e.g. have a look at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068827/how-do-i-send-html-email-via-java/5068907#5068907)).

Which version of Keycloak are you using? Comparing the source code of 'FreeMarkerEmailProvider' in [tag 1.2.0.Final](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/1.2.0.Final/forms/email-freemarker/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/FreeMarkerEmailProvider.java#L142) and on [branch 1.3.x](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/1.3.x/forms/email-freemarker/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/FreeMarkerEmailProvider.java#L168) lets me assume that Keycloak is able to handle `text/html` at least from version 1.3.x on.

But again: I am not familiar with Keycloak...